# IEnumerable & IEnumerator Suffix

Tags: .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

If you have a class that implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` but does not implement `ICollection`, `IList` or `ISet` what suffix do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard one without having the concrete type - but maybe I would just add "Source" or "s" (like Apple**s**, Apple**Source**) or simple Sequence (don't like enumeration) (AppleSeqence)

Comment: I have a type that represent an IPv4 Cidr. This type returns a sequence of IPAddress objects that are contained in the Cidr. I like your suffix. The source that was handed to me used Collection which rubbed me the wrong way as it isn't a proper collection.

Thanks!

Comment: if you like the answer you might want to mark it as usefull (arrow up) or even as "answer" ;)